# Unable to use macros from the rsfuzzy crate

Tags: macros, rust

I have a project that tries to use a macro from [rsfuzzy](https://github.com/auseckas/rsfuzzy):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rsfuzzy;

fn main() {
    fz_input_var!();
}
```

When I compile, I get errors like:

```
<rsfuzzy macros>:3:22: 3:41 error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `fuzzy::mf` [E0433]
<rsfuzzy macros>:3 let mut vars : Vec < fuzzy:: mf:: MfType > = Vec:: new (  ) ; $ (
```

When i use the 'extern crate rsfuzzy as fuzzy' as sugested, i get another list of errors:

```
failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `TXParserError` [E0433]at line 9 col 1 in <rsfuzzy macros>
unresolved name `TXParserError::from_complex` [E0425]at line 9 col 1 in <rsfuzzy macros>
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

The "rsfuzzy" crate exhibits poor coding practices which seem to be causing this problem. Here's an example of [the first macro I found](https://github.com/auseckas/rsfuzzy/blob/8dcfba6c7393af6ef7445641aa44b2c3d03448da/src/lib.rs#L261-L281):

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! fz_input_var {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut vars: Vec<fuzzy::mf::MfType> = Vec::new();
            $(
                let value = match $x.0 {
                    "triangle" => fuzzy::mf::Triangle::new($x.1, $x.2),
                    "trapezoid" => fuzzy::mf::Trapezoid::new($x.1, $x.2),
                    "up" => fuzzy::mf::Up::new($x.1, $x.2),
                    "down" => fuzzy::mf::Down::new($x.1, $x.2),
                    _ => return Err(TXParserError::from_complex("No MF found for type", $x.0))

                };
               vars.push(value);

            )*
            fuzzy::InputVar::new(vars)
        }
    };
}
```

You can see that the macro **hardcodes** the name of the crate to be `fuzzy`. A better-written crate solves this problem via the [`$crate` macro variable](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/macros.html#the-variable-crate).

You should submit a pull request or issue to the original project. As a workaround in the meantime, you can rename the crate when you import it:

```
extern crate rsfuzzy as fuzzy;
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried that, it solves the errors, but new ones appear.